# Same question appears under Linked and Related headings?

Tags: feature-request, linked-questions

Please forgive and advise me if an analogous question has been asked previously.

If a question already figures under the heading "Linked", is it possible for a user to instruct the website to desist from displaying the same question again under the heading "Related"?
Example from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/511326/53259):

[image]

Comment: I think I saw this as a request on Meta SO before, I'll drudge up the link if I can find it.

Comment: Hmm, maybe not quite. There was [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48624/linked-and-related-sections-contain-duplicate-links-to-questions) question that asks that it not happen in the first place, but it was marked [status-bydesign] three years ago.